# EF Core Scaffolded data and Property Changed

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-core, observable, mvvm-toolkit

I have a WPF application (MVVM Toolkit) with a data model which was scaffolded using EFcore tools from a database. The resulting model for one specific class looks like this:

```
public partial class BomLine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string? Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string? ManufacturerPartNumber { get; set; }

    public string? InternalPartNumberSelected { get; set; }
}
```

A list of such items `ObservableCollection<BomLine>` are displayed in a `ListView`. This works as expected. There is an additional binding on the value of `InternalPartNumberSelected` which gives the respective line a distinct color.

Now, when the value of `InternalPartNumberSelected` changes, no PropertyChanged event is fired (of course, there is no `[ObservableProperty]` or other explicit RaisePropertyChanged command.

I could now change the Scaffolded data to

```
public partial class BomLine : ObservableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string? Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string? ManufacturerPartNumber { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty] string? _internalPartNumberSelected;
}
```

This would make the color change visible because now a Property Change event is fired and the Binding re-evalued.

Yet, this seems like a bad solution because it requires tinkering with scaffolded data (which would be overwritten).

Is there a "correct" approach to that problem? I'm using .net core 8 / efcore 8, WPF, MVVM toolkit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/n-tier-architecture/info

Comment: I would copy data from EF classes to viewmodel classes. You can use mappers like mapperly or automapper to reduce the coding. You can make viewmodels self tracking so you know which have changed. Then back viewmodel to ef class for updates. In most big systems ef would be used on a web server and the UI calling a web API for data. In which case there'd be dto as well.

Comment: By having seeming duplication you have a natural fracture point for any transformation. Each layer has only that whiich is necessary. Eg you don't end up with Wpf commands in an EF model.

Comment: That's somewhat funny. A while ago I asked a similar question which got heavily down-voted because it's "a bad idea to have the same data in multiple places". I thought it was strange because I wanted to separate the data access layer from the presentation logic. Looking at your answer, it appears I was right all along. Thank you for mentioning auto-mapper. I will need to look into that.

Comment: Despite the similar functionality, your BomLine class is not a DTO of general use. This class was created specifically for parsing SQL queries and reflects the state of the database. "Change InternalPartNumberSelected" does not apply to this functionality. If, in the data architecture you have chosen, you need to change any BomLine property, then it must be changed “through the database”. That is, the change was written to the database, if the entry is correct, then a new BomLine instance was created with new values and transferred to the Model’s consumers.

Comment: The idea is to immediately write the data back to the database (the new internal part number) and then show the change so in fact it's somewhat both. I wanted to use the tracking feature of the context to simply update the value. But to show the actual change, I need to trigger the view to show the updated value as well. Otherwise the data will only be stored but the change is not visible by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep separation of EF from view models by using an approach explained at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject#wrapping-a-non-observable-model. In your case it would be something like this:

```
public class BomLineViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly BomLine model;

    public BomLineViewModel(BomLine model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get => model.Id;
        // no setter, Id is readonly
    }

    public int ProjectId
    {
        get => model.ProjectId;
        set => SetProperty(model.ProjectId, value, model, (m, v) => m.ProjectId = v);
    }

    public string? Manufacturer
    {
        get => model.Manufacturer;
        set => SetProperty(model.Manufacturer, value, model, (m, v) => m.Manufacturer = v);
    }

    public string? ManufacturerPartNumber
    {
        get => model.ManufacturerPartNumber;
        set => SetProperty(model.ManufacturerPartNumber, value, model, (m, v) => m.ManufacturerPartNumber = v);
    }

    public string? InternalPartNumberSelected
    {
        get => model.InternalPartNumberSelected;
        set => SetProperty(model.InternalPartNumberSelected, value, model, (m, v) => m.InternalPartNumberSelected = v);
    }
}
```

That way you can add even other things to the view model and they won't affect EF.

Comment: That's beautiful. In my case it's enough to make 2 properties with a setter and keep all others readonly. Now I can easily assign the new value to the ObservableProperty, the backing model gets updated, the change shows in MVVM/WPF and I can simply call "_context.SaveChanges" and it is persisted to the database. Just perfect.